# How to remove programmatically the security protection of a copied file in network directory?

Tags: c#, .net, security, copy-protection

i have a file in a network directory and this file it's been previously copied, and i want to operate with this file.
But, in Windows Xp, the file have this security protection / block:

(sorry it's in italian)

[image: security]

I want to programmatically remove this security protection in C#.

Thanks in advance!

M.

Comment: Is the protection not there for a reason?

Comment: The protection is there because the file is from another computer. But i want to use the file, that it's seems locked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unblock File from within .net 4 c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374673/unblock-file-from-within-net-4-c)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617509/unblock-a-file-with-powershell (I know this is powershell, but provides a bit more background which might also help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open this file for write `yourfile.exe:Zone.Identifier` and close it, so it gets emptyed.