# Antivirus blocking file downloads by a running windows service

Tags: windows, windows-services, antivirus

I have a running winservice which downloads an exe to disk and runs the logic from that binary.

Everytime I download , I have the AVG antivirus prompting the user to verify if it can run it or move it to vault.

I would be running it on servers where there wont be any user intervention.
How can I get around this ?

Firefox/Windows autoupdater for instance,seems to autoupgrade seemlessly even with the antivirus installed. How does it work ?

Does getting whitelisted the only way around this ?

Comment: *where* is the AVG prompting the user?  Windows services don't have a UI...

Comment: How are you downloading this file? Do you need all features of AVG on your servers or could you disable "Safe Downloads"-feature on them and just be extra careful when downloading other stuff?

Comment: Try superuser.com for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

If AVG anti-virus is claiming that a file is a virus, and you are **certain** that it is not, you can [submit a false positive report](http://samplesubmit.avg.com/us-en/false-detection) to them.

They will examine the file (included in your report) and generally will update virus definitions within 1-2 weeks to exclude that file.

If you cannot wait that long, you can install a different anti-virus solution.

If you are downloading the file from an **untrusted source** (from Windows perspective, e.g. not from your intranet) the file may be marked as such.  AVG could be responding to that.  Check the file by right-clicking on it with Windows Explorer and selecting Properties.  If there is an *Unblock* button, that is the issue.  Add the location the file is being downloaded from to the list of trusted locations.

Alternatively, you can use PowerShell to unblock the file

[Unblock a file with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617509/unblock-a-file-with-powershell)

Comment: I don't think that AVG says it's a virus, it's probably just flagging that an executable that was downloaded from the internet is about to be executed and want to know if to sandbox it or not.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren: Yeah, added that possibility too.

Comment: Thanks for the replies..
I will try checking the trusted location bit..

AVG doesnt really say its a virus.
 I tried downloading a .DAT file instead of an .EXE to test and AVG again prompted me with a  "Do you want to move it to Vault/Not " prompt..

I cant really uninstall AVG since its a client machine.

Comment: @user1621026: Try the second suggestion, which is to see if the Untrusted attribute is set.

Comment: Thanks,strangely that doesnt seem to be case,its trusted. I actually created a dll instead of an exe and it actually seems to do just fine with no antivirus issues but then that doesnt solve my problem.