# Batch file to unblock files copied from internet

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

When we copy files (dll) from internet, Win7 blocks it. The unblock option appears as in the following image when we take the file properties. What command can I use to unblock the file from a batch file?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Supposedly this should work:

```
echo.>myDownloadedFile.exe:Zone.Identifier
```

See a more detailed discussion here, [Unblock a file with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617509/unblock-a-file-with-powershell), which also describes other approaches using Powershell and the `streams` tool from SysInternals.

Comment: For a filename with spaces in it, this works:
`echo.>"myDownloadedFile.exe":Zone.Identifier`

Comment: what does `echo.>` do ?

Comment: `echo.` echoes nothing, and `>` outputs this nothing to the specified file. Or in this case, to the zone identifier of the file.

Answer (score 12):

To do one is as per other suggestions.
i.e either:

```
echo.>myDownloadedFile.dll:Zone.Identifier
```

or

```
Unblock-File myDownloadedFile.dll
```

but to do it 'bulk' as OP requested:

```
get-childitem *.jpg, *.gif | Unblock-File
```

or in DOS:

```
FOR %a in (*.jpg *.gif) do (echo.>%a:Zone.Identifier)
```

Comment: This bulk operation didn't work on Windows 10. I had to use double `%`.

Comment: @akinuri I tend towards Powershell solutions on Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

You can use streams -d path/to/file.zip
This can be found here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440