# Could not load file or assembly (nopcommerce 3.5) when changing to release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce

I have a new nopcommerce 3.5 website that i want to publish
and on debug it all was well 
but as soon i changed to release im getting this error

```
Error   1   Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\User\Desktop\nop\packages\Autofac.3.5.2\lib\net40\Autofac.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)   C:\Users\User\Desktop\nop\Libraries\Nop.Services\SGEN   Nop.Services
```

and i looked all over the web and did all i could and it is just not working

what i did.

1. clean and rebuild
2. restart vs
3. i re-downloaded a fresh copy of the code and the same happened
4. deleted all the references and rebuilt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK here is how i solved it.

The files were locked by windows and its only visible in debug

I had to go to each .dll file that showed up in the error, 
and in the properties there was a button UNBLOCK and ones i applied the changes the errors was gone

Comment: I had the same problem and this did solve it, however I had to unblock each dll manually. I wonder if there is a way to unblock all dll's in a given directory or project... this is extremely cumbersome.

Comment: i tried a few scripts and non of them did the trick, so i did each one and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of unblock all files one by one, you can do it from root folder by using Windows PowerShell:

dir D:\Projects\Nop -recurse | Unblock-File

Comment: I tried it and it didn't unlock all the files, you can try it but if it does not work Check each file

Comment: The Unblock-File does not work in PS2.0, please help to check the version by this command: PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Answer (score 1):

To unblock files use this command on Windows Powershell:

```
gci PASTE_FOLDER_PATH_HERE\*.dll -Recurse | Unblock-File
```

1) "gci" is used to load all files located under the specified path. 
2) "-Recurse" is used to load files located in sub folders under the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It worked for me in a way right click on **NopCommerce\packages\Autofac.3.5.2\lib\net40\AutoFac.dll** then **Unblock** & finally click on **OK**, it will resolve this issue. I resolved this issue in this way.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38517840/1586498

```
get-childitem *.*| Unblock-File
```

For those limited in their PowerShell options:

```
FOR %a in (*.*) do (echo.>%a:Zone.Identifier)
```