# How to check file extension?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a small batch script to remove zone identifiers <sup>[[SO]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263523/batch-file-to-unblock-files-copied-from-internet)</sup> from URL files (Internet Shortcut). I've improved it to work with multiple files/folders. I just select the files/folders and drop them on the batch script, and the script removes the zone identifiers.

When looping a folder's contents, there seems to be a convenient way to target specific files, e.g. `FOR %%j IN (%%i\*.url)` for URL files, but if I have only a list of files, how do I check if the file is a URL file, that is its extension is `.url`?

I've found a way <sup>[[ss64]](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)</sup> to return the extension `%%~xi` (returns `.url`; `i` is the loop variable), but couldn't make it work.

```
REM loop arguments
FOR %%i IN (%*) DO (
    REM check if the argument is a directory
    IF EXIST %%~si\NUL (
        REM loop children (filtering url files)
        FOR %%j IN (%%i\*.url) DO (
            echo %%j
            REM remove zone identifier
            echo. > %%j:Zone.Identifier
        )
    ) ELSE (
        REM check if the argument is a url file    <<< how?

        REM returns the extension: .url
        echo %%~xi

        REM doesn't work. why?
        IF %%~xi == ".url" (
            echo %%i
            echo. > %%i:Zone.Identifier
        )

    )
)
```

Doing simply `IF %%~xi == ".url"` doesn't work. I'm not that familiar with batch scripts, so I must be missing something. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems just like a little typo.

It should work like this:

```
IF "%%~xi" == ".url"
```

Comment: _*facepalm*_ Indeed, it does! :)

Comment: I just dropped a bunch of files and folders (together) on the batch file, and it correctly printed the URL files (skipped other files: pdf, txt, etc.). Quoting the `"%%~xi"` did the trick.

Comment: @akinuri: change `"%~x1"` (extension of first parameter) to `"%%~xi" (extension of the filename hold by the `for`-variable `%%i`)` to make it correct.