# Operation failed, unable to locate the solution directory

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I'm new to ASP.NET and have been working through some tutorials in VS 2013. I just tried to open up Nuget by clicking on Website > Manage Nuget Packages, but got this error message:

"Operation failed. Unable to locate solution directory. Please ensure that the solution has been saved."

I can't seem to find anything online about how to fix this, and Nuget is definitely installed and everything is saved. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message suggests?  Saving the solution you just created somewhere before doing this step?

Comment: One of the things I'm not clear on is exactly what that means: I've saved everything so I thought I had done that. Is there something else I need to do to save the solution?

Comment: Ah, thanks very much. The ctrl+shift+S worked - I guess I didn't understand that I needed to save it as a .sln file. I'm still quite new to VS. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In VS2010 <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> saves everything.

Selecting the solution in the Solution Explorer and then choose

> File | Save

saves the solution.

Keep in mind that if you donwload files from the internet those files can be blocked. You can unblock them by going to the properties of the file in the windows explorer and click unblock. Or you could use powershell as [shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617509/unblock-a-file-with-powershell)