# Giving a downloaded powershell script permission to run from a C# application?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I just encountered this, went through a ton of SO questions, and still cannot see a solution.

So, I have a C# application ("ClickOnce"). the C# application is made to run this MyScript.ps1 PowerShell script, and everything worked fine on the development computer.

Then, I try on another computer - install the C# application, then I download a zip, unpack it, and it has the powershell script `MyScript.ps1`; I set up the C# application to use the local path to `MyScript.ps1`, and I run it. This is what I get inside the application:

```
check_script err:File C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyFolder\MyScript.ps1 cannot be loaded because 
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I have then tried in Administrator PowerShell from [ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117421/ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system) :

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
```

None of this helps the script run from the C# application.

In previous attempts (which I unfortunately did not record), I made the script run otherwise (e.g. if you call in cmd.exe `powershell .\MyScript.ps1`, it works without any prompts - I think this was with [Unblock a file with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617509/unblock-a-file-with-powershell)); also, if you run `dir /r` in cmd.exe (NOT in powershell, that command fails there), I can see e.g.

```
C:\>dir /r .
 Volume in drive C is Windows
...
 Directory of C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyFolder\

12/09/2023  14.16    <DIR>          .
12/09/2023  14.16    <DIR>          ..
12/09/2023  14.13             4.605 MyScript.ps1
12/09/2023  14.14    <DIR>          subdir01
...
12/09/2023  14.13            60.356 libwinpthread-1.dll
                                 98 libwinpthread-1.dll:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
...
12/09/2023  14.13             5.131 MYBATCH.bat
                                 98 MYBATCH.bat:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
```

So, Zone.Identifier* is gone on MyScript.ps1 - which is probably why the script now runs from cmd.exe (or double-click - cannot tell, it ends too fast), but that still does not work for C#.

What else can I do, to give this script permission to run from a C# application, started by a normal user?

Answer (score 1):

- If you're fine with ***persistently* setting the [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies)** on a given machine *ahead* of executing your C# application, you can do the following (unless the policy is controlled via *GPOs* (Group Policy Objects), but note that choosing `Unrestricted` will *prompt for consent* to execute scripts downloaded from the web, whereas the commonly used `RemoteSigned` policy more safely *refuses to execute*.

  - From an *elevated* session (run as admin), you can use `-Scope AllUsers` to set the policy for *all* users:

    ```
    #requires -RunAsAdministrator
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope AllUsers -Force Unrestricted
    ```
  - From a non-elevated session, you can only set the policy for the *current* user:

    ```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -Force Unrestricted
    ```
- A simpler solution is to ***transiently* change the execution policy *for the C# application process only***, using the appropriate configuration of the initial session state via the PowerShell SDK.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942672/45375) for details.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got it: if you run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in an administrative PowerShell, it does the settings for the "current user", which is in this case Administrator - not whatever is the current user!

So I opened a *normal* cmd exe (that is, as the normal user on this PC), and then:

```
C:\Users\User>cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...>powershell
Windows PowerShell
...
PS C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...> Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
Undefined
PS C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
PS C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...> exit
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\...>my_csharp_program.exe
```

I did a `cd` to the directory where the C# program got installed, not sure if that was necessary, but it is visible that "CurrentUser" had an Undefined ExecutionPolicy, and after setting it to Unrestricted, exiting PowerShell, and running the .exe directly from cmd.exe ended up working (for me).